# Creating web page/PDF from a Form

Tags: wordpress, pdf

I'm trying to *create a webpage that allows users to fill in fields on a form* (dropdown boxes, images, and free text fields)

On submission this form would create either a webpage or a PDF that could then be saved for their records, I need to design the template and specify the location of where the results show up.

Ideally it would actually be emailed to them and myself or at-least stored in a database. Should you be wondering, it is to create well organised and consistent birth certificates across a group of animal breeders.

The site is wordpress based, I have discovered that Gravity PDF is likely my best bet to achieve this using a plugin but thought I would ask the question in case there is a more user friendly solution.

Thanks in advance folks!

Comment: Why not just provide a PDF form to the users? Are there dynamic components which could not be dealt with with a pre-filling tool?

Comment: I'll give that a shot, one of the main features is the ability for users to specify their own logo. If a PDF form handle all of this that would certain be good solution from a UX point of view.

Comment: In order to get a logo into the form, without server-side filling, the users would need either Acrobat, or Adobe (Acrobat) Reader XI or newer. In the second case, the logo would have to be available as PDF. With server-side filling, it is definitely possible; what and how would depend on the implementation. In any case, the PDF could be used as a front-end (and have the logo transferred either as a file annotation, or via a separate channel).